# how to integrate the function {Exp[2/r + 2 r] - 1}^(1/2) with respect to r?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have tried to integrate the function `{Exp[2/r + 2 r] - 1}^(1/2)` using `Integrate` command but no result came, can anybody please help me out with this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Please show us _exactly_ how you use `Integrate` and what is the result. Also, note that curly braces `{}` in Mathematica denotes [`List`s](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html), and you should probably use round braces `()`.

Comment: Are you sure that there exists an analytic result?

Comment: It has an interesting series expansion around $r = i$ and that looks like $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } (r-i)^{\frac{1}{2} (2 n+1)} z(n)$ where $z(n)$ is just a list of complex numbers with no easy discernable pattern except they spiral out from 0 and always have rational real and imaginary parts.  I don't think this helps you much though.

Comment: Hello Domen, I have used round braces, but still didnot work.

Comment: The function has two essential singularities at 0 and oo. The square root is  a factor 1/2 in the exponent to cancel the factor 2.  I dont expect nothing.